# How to Make An App That Notifies On Full Charge With A Sound

Tags: android

> Hello Programmers,
>   I Am Trying to create an app that plays a set sound when the battery is full how do i do so?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take this [tour] before proceeding.

Comment: have you tried developing the app yet? If yes, please tell the problem you are facing. If not, please start developing the app.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: start here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: i had a problem getting the battery notification lol i knew how to get notification and the battery power but not linking them

Comment: but what about the notification wouldnt i need the notification manager

Comment: after i make it work how should i get notificatioon outside app

Answer (score 0):

Got something useful by googling.

```
// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                 status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// How are we charging?
int chargePlug =     batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

Use if command to do what you want when BATTERY_STATUS_FULL is reached. If you never did programming then sorry, first learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Shahbaz's answer seems to be correct all I would add to it is to implement an if statment surrounding the battery status e.g.

`if(status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){
//Play sound using Android MediaPlayer
}`

and then implement the android MediaPlayer object in order to play your sound, it's pretty simple to use once you've read the info on it here's the link! 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Good Luck!